# Is there a way to use Excel solver to find optimal distribution throughout the months?

Tags: excel, linear-programming, solver

This is a question about solver with linear programming.

I am not looking for help with my exercise, I just want to understand the behavior of the tool, because the output is not what I was expecting.

The example below shows what I was looking for and what I was able to accomplish. Moreover, I provide details of the “unexpected behavior”.

Moving on… I was trying to create a method to plan the receiving of products throughout the year respecting the company’s budget.

In row 3, from column H to S, there is the allowed volume to receive per month.
[image]

To simplify the example, let’s say that there are 5 models (Model Id – column D). The number of stores that should get the item is displayed in “Accumulative Stores” (column E). There is also the volume that is sent to stores in the first batch (“Initial Allocation” – column F). The “Total volume” (column G) shows the total volume that must be received by the company.

In rows 7 to 11, from column H to S, there is the final planned volume by Model ID per month.
[image]

The rules to plan the receiving are:

• If the “Total volume” >= “Accumulative Stores” * “Initial Allocation” * 1.1 then it is mandatory that the first batch contains the necessary volume for the assigned stores plus 10% (initial replenishment).

• If the “Total volume” < “Accumulative Stores” * “Initial Allocation” * 1.1 then the first batch must be the “Total volume”.

• The pending volume can be split in up to 3 batches and each batch must have a volume of at least 120 units.

• The remaining batches after initial receiving must be received in straight months (it is not allowed to skip a month).

• Finally, if there is some volume left after the initial batch and the following 3 deliveries, the missing volume should be allocated in one or more of the available months.

Initially I created a table with binary values to allocate the initial allocation + initial replenishment (the 10%).

[image]

I also created a table with binary values to accommodate the initial allocation of the items without enough volume to have replenishment.

[image]

Then I created a table with binary values to define which months should have split batches.

[image]

There is a table that is used only for the constraints to avoid having split batches arriving in earlier months than the initial batch.

[image]

And the last table was supposed to have the values to fill-up the distribution of volumes for the month and items that were not full.

[image]

The result of my work can distribute initial allocation, initial replenishment, and split batches in straight months right after the initial volume. However, when I add to solver the option to change the value of the “Fill-up volume” table, the tool keeps the table with zeros and loses the ability to perform what it was doing previously.

Can anyone explain why?

I am adding links to download 2 XLSX files with the 2 different solver set-ups (one includes the “Fill-up volume” table as variable cells).

Obs 1: I chose XLSX file to be sure that there are no macros in the file that could cause trouble to you computer.

Obs 2: because original MS Excel Solver has limitations in the number of variables and constraints, I am using OpenSolver add-in.

Thank you.

[File 1](https://www.supply360.com.br/stackoverflow/File1.xlsx)
[File 2](https://www.supply360.com.br/stackoverflow/File2.xlsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 weeks I decided to take a second look at exercise and try to solve the problem.

With my knowledge, I really could not figure out what the problem was, so I decided on a new approach.

So, instead of setting binary variables for defined values, I used the Big M method to create something similar to a conditional variable without losing the linearity.

Because there were not many views to my post, I don’t know whether my answer to the question is going to help others, but here it goes anyway, especially because I used the Big M method and there are some users that could benefit, even though their questions may not be related to my original post.

Here it goes:
The initial setup was the same, except that the value for each month in columns K to V now point to the new auxiliar tables.
[image]

I decided to use a “two Big M”. One to set the minimum amount protecting initial allocation and another one to complete the volume respecting the minimum of 120 units.

For the first one I created a table with binary variables and a table that could have values 0 or >= the “Min initial”.
[image]

For the second one I created a table with binary variables and a table that could have values 0 or >= 120.
[image]

The Big M constraints were applied to each variable cell that contains the months in the following way:
• Cell <= Binary * BigM
• Cell >= Binary * MinValue

I made available one example file for the ones who want to check the full solver constraints and variables cells. It is a XLSX file to prevent security problems with macros.
[Download file](https://www.supply360.com.br/stackoverflow/File3.xlsx)

Again, because original MS Excel Solver has limitations in the number of variables and constraints, I used OpenSolver add-in.

Thank you